# Получить id с помощью username

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть таблица `tb_user` со столбцами `user_id` и `username`. В массиве `$usernames[]` храниться **username** некоторых пользователей. Теперь я хочу имея **username** пользователей, получить доступ к **user_id** этих пользователей.
Вот код:

```
$usernames = [eqor123, dima567, max100500];
$user_id = [];
    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($usernames); $i++) {
        $userId = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT `user_id` FROM `tb_users` WHERE `username`='".$usernames[$i]."'");
        $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userId);
        $user_id[] = $result['user_id'];
    }
```

но код неправилный при `print_r($user_id)` в ответе дается **id** только первого пользователя (то есть 1), а мне нужно **id** всех выбранных пользователей.

Comment: А `$user_id` заранее объявили?

Comment: @Suvitruf Исправил

Comment: И опять SQL-инъекция.

Comment: @andreymal Это пробный код. Реализация будет через PDO

Comment: Так сделайте сразу через PDO, возможно ваша проблема решится, потому что визуально (кроме отсутствия хотя-бы mysql_real_escape_string)  придраться не к чему.

Comment: @ruslan4742 так сделайте сразу через PDO, там можно составить WHERE IN запрос и запихнуть весь массив сразу без цикла, смотрите пример например здесь https://stackoverflow.com/a/14767651/5418360

Answer (score 0):

1. После SELECT  ты указываешь поля, которые хочешь получить из таблицы. Можешь указать несколько `SELECT user_id, username FROM ...` или вообще все вот так: `SELECT * FROM ...`
2. Можешь не делать по запросу на каждого пользователя (слишком долго получается), а сделать запрос

`$preparedForSQLUsernames = [];
foreach ($usernames as $username) {
    //экранируем строки (для защиты от инъекций) и оборачиваем в кавычки чтобы потом использовать в запросе
    $preparedForSQLUsernames[] = "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconn, $username) "'";}
$query = "SELECT * FROM tb_users WHERE username IN (" . implode(",", $preparedForSQLUsernames) . ")";`

3. Чтобы не заниматься такой ересью, посмотри на класс PDO http://php.net/manual/ru/class.pdo.php

Comment: боюсь вот прямо так в PDO она не решилась, массив как один параметр в IN передать вроде нельзя (если я не ошибаюсь). но по быстрому сгенерить строку из `?` и передать массив так же в execute конечно будет все равно гораздо проще, чем всякие escape и т.п.

Comment: Да, правильно, проверил сам только что на рабочей БД - массивы не биндятся. Ближайшее решение здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Comment: Решение вашего вопроса здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617620/mysql-where-in-array-string-username